# Assigning numbers via user input in list as integer in Python

Tags: python, list, user-input

here’s the program

```
assignments = (input(“assignments:”).split(",") #enter number separeted by comma
print(type(assignments[0]))
```

output is class `str`

how to save the numbers as integers not as string,
I have tried

```
assignments = int(input("assignments:")).split(",")
```

but it gives me error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: #numbers which I
>   enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast the entire `list` (or the input string that contains all the commas) to `int` as a whole, you would have to do it for the split tokens individually, e.g. with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
assignments = [int(x) for x in input(“assignments:”).split(",")]
```

or using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
assignments = list(map(int, input(“assignments:”).split(",")))
```